# get slide with your finger in libgdx , solution to the class

Tags: java, android, libgdx, swipe, genymotion

I'm applying this class:
https://truongtx.me/2013/04/27/simple-swipe-gesture-detection-for-libgdx/
because I need to take the direction of the slide over the surface of the screen , with libgdx .
I'm using genymotion as emulator and would like to know , since I do not work class , if it is a problem that genymotion not detect the slide with the mouse , or if it does not the class . Thank you

Comment: So your code isn't working as intended and you're wondering whether it's genymotion or the code that doesn't work? Just making sure, since your English isn't the best :)

Comment: exactly , is the code or genymotion ?